# How data toggle target wait for axios success/fail in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-modal

I want to wait the axios success to trigger the modal, or fail to not trigger the modal without changing any existing styles. Current code is always trigger without waiting the axios response, even though v-if has been added.

Current code:

```
<template>
<div>
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <a @click="func()" class="btn btn-sm btn-round btn-success save-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#success-save">submit</a>
    </div>


    <div v-if="modalDisplay" class="modal modal-top fade" id="success-save" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h3 class="text-center" style="color:white;"><strong>Success</strong></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            modalDisplay: false,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        func() {
            axios.post('/some/uri', {
                'content': 'abc',
            })
                .then(response => {
                    this.modalDisplay = true;
                });
        },
    }
</script>
```

I have tried relocating v-if and others, but it still doesn't work, or it already works but the style has changed, your solution will be very helpful, thankyou!

Edit:
I'm using Vue 2.6.11
Modified the code

Comment: Can you tell me if you are using vue 2 or vue 3?

Comment: So if you add console.log into `.then(response => {` handler it immediatly outputs to console?

Comment: @devil-0-per vue 2.6.11

Comment: @Anatoly yes if success

Comment: Maybe your request is too fast? )

Comment: but I think it's not the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

In Vue 2.x, templates should contain only one element inside it.
Try pushing all the tags into a div like this

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <a @click="func()" class="btn btn-sm btn-round btn-success save-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#success-save">submit</a>
    </div>
    <div v-if="modalDisplay" class="modal modal-top fade" id="success-save" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h3 class="text-center" style="color:white;"><strong>Success</strong></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Also add a cache block to your axios call

```
axios.post('/some/uri', {
            'content': 'abc',
        })
            .then(response => {
                this.modalDisplay = true;
            })
            .catch(error=> {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

In Vue 3, you can use [fragments](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/new/fragments.html#_2-x-syntax) to achieve this without wrapping into a single node

You can find the implementation [here](https://codepen.io/devil-0-per/pen/dyXrMGY)

Comment: is your API failing? do you have any logs on it?
You can add a cache block to `axios` request to find it here as well.

Comment: I don't think the problem is that. The button is executed first before waiting for axios to succeed (which just changes the modalDisplay value). Therefore, the problem is, how to wait for Axios to be successful and then toggle the modalDisplay without changing the existing style.

Comment: Check this implemetation here.
The button shows up after the click on button

https://codepen.io/devil-0-per/pen/dyXrMGY